# Fatal error when building .go package

Tags: go

I'm trying to install a go package. I cloned the package, ran the following commands to build it:

```
$go get -v -d

Fetching https://golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/net", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/net"} at https://golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/net?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/net?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/net (download)

$go build *.go
# github.com/moul/http2curl
gccgo: error: $HOME/go/src/github.com/moul/http2curl/http2curl.go: No such file or directory
gccgo: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
# github.com/pkg/errors
gccgo: error: $HOME/go/src/github.com/pkg/errors/errors.go: No such file or directory
gccgo: error: $HOME/go/src/github.com/pkg/errors/stack.go: No such file or directory
gccgo: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
# golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix
gccgo: error: $HOME/go/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix/list.go: No such file or directory
gccgo: error: $HOME/go/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix/table.go: No such file or directory
gccgo: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I tried cloning github.com/moul/http2curl to $HOME/go/src/github.com/moul/http2curl and the http2curl.go file is exactly in the path specified and yet it still says No such file or directory. 
How do I build this?

Comment: You build a package by name, not by trying to specify individual files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what plain `go get -v -d` gets you but you should specify the package(s) that you want to install.
So what you should do is something like this:

`$go get github.com/moul/http2curl`

Without the `-d` flag this should download **and install** the package `http2curl` for you. But if you use the `-d` flag, you can install the package by first moving to the package's directory.

`$cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/moul/http2curl`

And then running build (without *.go).

`$go build`